# What does 'integration density' mean?

Tags: integrated-circuit

What does 'integration density' in the context of integrated circuits and electronics mean? I've seen the term tossed around a lot, but I've never found a satisfactory definition.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "integration" is as in "integrated circuit". A high integration density means a large number of components (usually transistors, in contexts where integration density is being discussed) in a small area.

Comment: "mostly transistors, in most cases". The double usage of most is kind of confusing me. Do you mean that in most cases, most of the components discussed are transistors, i.e. some components aren't, or was it just tautological use of most? Also, what might the other components be?

Comment: @Phaptitude I just mean that an IC can have any sort of components, but of the kinds where we are usually talking about "integration density", we are usually talking about ICs that are almost entirely transistors: CPUs and the like.

Comment: Things not mostly transistors: ROM is made out of diodes. MEMS (eg accelerometers) are mechanical systems built on ICs.

Answer (score 0):

Low integration density - CPU made of discrete transistors (takes up half a sq kilometer)

High integration density - CPU made of silicon monocrystal (takes up half a sq centimeter)

Comment: Does a CPU of discrete transistors count as "integrated" at all?

Comment: Is this a philosophical question? If so, then as "integrated" I only imagine a theoretical quantity. Everything heterogeneous is therefore _integrated_, only with varying value...

Comment: No, it's just that an "integrated circuit" means *not constructed from discrete components*

Comment: Fair enough....